# How to split Devise user into different types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to split Devise user into different types? Like, for example: user go to the registration page and sign up, but based on whether they're a teacher or a student they will registered and login to see different navbar? How would I do that using a checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is excellently explained in their [Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role).

In my opinion you should consider option number 1. and 3:

- Separate model for student and teacher, if they have different attributes
- One model for both with additional column `role`. It will be appropriate if models have the same attributes.

Then on your views just check what is the role / type of user and present proper content.